# HTML - Which element to output text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing a little chat application where I receive messages from a server, which I would like to display to a user. As I'm more of a backend guy, and lacking experience in frontend development, I don't know which element would be suited best to output the text.

Two options come to my mind:

1. Using a plain `div`
2. Using a `textarea` (as far as I understand, this is intended to be used for input).

(Would also be nice if I could somehow fade in the text using JQuery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For readonly messages- better use `<div>`
- otherwise use `<textarea>`\ textbox(`<input type="text"...>`).

Fading it is simple, if the element id is `foo`:

```
$('#foo').fadeIn();
```

Comment: So, should I use a div as a container for the messages, and insert every new message as a p?

Comment: @OliverWeiler. Sounds like a legit idea. With HTML + CSS you can do almost anything with anything. you can make a div to look like a textarea and the opposite, (though would just pick div cuz it looks like a div naturally...)

Comment: @OliverWeiler. What you customer choose, it's not my decision. **:)**

Comment: @OliverWeiler. It's like asking me what should you use `java` or `.Net` or `php`. The answer is, _"out of my scope."_ good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use a  tag for the content and with Jquery you could append a span or a new paragraph tag for every new message:

```
<div id="chatContent">

</div>
```

Then in JQuery you could do:

```
function chatMessageRecieved(message) {
   $("#chatContent").append("<p> " + messsage + "</p>")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a div, textarea is effectively for input

For jquery : http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Ex :

```
$('#div').fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

Comment: habits to do it, i use always this one :)

Comment: Another thing, I would't say he _"have"_ to use div. it's recommended though.

Comment: yes :)
I use always fadeTo because is some situation you can play with opacity, plus if you have to hide it it's only one function that you have to remember, i just find it easier ;)